# webgl replace program shader

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to swap the fragement-shader used in a program. The fragment-shaders all have the same variables, just different calculations. I am trying to provide alternative shaders for lower level hardware.

I end up getting single color outputs (instead of a texture), does anyone have an idea what I could be doing wrong? I know the shaders are being used, due to the color changing accordingly.

```
     //if I don't do this: 
     //WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: attachShader: shader attachment already has shader
gl.detachShader(program, _.attachedFS);
     //select a random shader, all using the same parameters
attachedFS = fragmentShaders[~~(Math.qrand()*fragmentShaders.length)];
     //attach the new shader
gl.attachShader(program, attachedFS); 
     //if I don't do this nothing happens
gl.linkProgram(program);
     //if I don't add this line:
     //globject.js:313 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniform2f: 
     //location not for current program
updateLocations();
```

Comment: You should arguably be creating multiple shader-programs, not changing the shaders on an existing shader-program. Create shader programs for every combination of features you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, after trying about everything else without result. It also explains why I was seeing a shader change, but just getting a flat color. I was not updating some of the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

- I am assuming you have called gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
- Have you tried to test the code on a different browser and see if you get the same behavior? (it could be standards implementation specific)
- Have you tried to delete the fragment shader (gl.deleteShader(attachedFS); ) right after detaching it. The
  previous shader may still have a pointer in memory.
- If this does not let you move forward, you may have to detach both shaders (vertex & frag) and reattach them or even recreate the program from scratch

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will give it a try and report back

Comment: Assuming that there's not a bug in the WebGL implementation or GPU driver detaching the shader shall be enough, no need to delete it nor recreate the whole program from scratch. Judging by the comments in the source provided by the OP i'd lean towards wrongly setup attribute pointers and/or varyings.